# UIAlert view triggered from CustomCell Class // Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uialertcontroller

I have a TableViewCell populated with CustomCells. In the customCells I have a button which I want to trigger an UIAlert.

Here is my code for the button in the CustomCell Class:

```
@IBAction func anzahlButton(sender: UIButton) {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Bitte gib Deine gewünschte Anzahl an:", message: nil, preferredStyle: .Alert)
    alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler {
        (tf:UITextField!) in
        tf.keyboardType = .NumberPad
        tf.addTarget(self, action: "textChanged:", forControlEvents: .EditingChanged)
    }

    func handler(act:UIAlertAction!) {
        let tf = alert.textFields![0] as UITextField
        let addItem = "\(tf.text)"
        var fixedToDoItems = ""
        anzahlText.setTitle("\(addItem)", forState: .Normal)
        //println("User entered \(addItem), tapped \(act.title)")
    }

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: handler))
    (alert.actions[1] as UIAlertAction).enabled = false

    TableViewController().presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

When I hit the button I get this alert: `Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7fc7f0cbc5c0> on <MyApp.TableViewController: 0x7fc7f0c965f0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`

I deed some resaerch on the debug-alert, but couldn't find an answer that is in swift and works for me... ;-)

Any ideas?

THX
//Seb

Comment: Your `presentViewController` call is being performed on a new instance of a tableviewcontroller - which is why it is not in the window hierarchy. One solution is to add a property to your cell class that holds a reference to your tableviewcontroller so that you can invoke the uialaert on it.

Comment: Thx @Paulw11! Sry, I'm pretty new to swift and don't quit know how to follow your advise. Would you have some kind of sample code for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your line `TableViewController().presentViewController`, TableViewController() actually creates a new instance of the view controller `TableViewController`. This instance is not the one currently displayed on the screen. Which is why you get the error that the view is not part of the window hierarchy.

In order to fix that move the `func anzahlButton(sender: UIButton)`  to the `TableViewController` file and then connect it to the button through `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function. remove the `@IBAction` part since we are no longer connecting the button through the interface builder.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell 
{
    // Your Code
    cell.button.addTarget(self, action: "anzahlButton:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
}
```

Then change the line

```
TableViewController().presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

to

```
self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Hi rakeshbs. Thx for your reply. I did as you advised and now get this error: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MyApp.CustomCell anzahlButton:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb660668320'` - in your line `cell.button.addTarget` what excactly is the "button"? Outlet? Identifier? IBAction...?

Comment: make an IBOutlet var of the button inside CustomCell. I thought you already had that. `IBOutlet var button`. connect it to through Interface Builder.

Comment: yeah I had but when i used it the app crashed. I made a new outlet now and it works like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: One more thing: The line `anzahlText.setTitle("\(addItem)", forState: .Normal)`actually changes the titel of the button beeing pressed. I changed the code now to the new outlet and the CustomCell class: `CustomCell().button.setTitle("\(addItem)", forState: .Normal)` This however gives me the following error for that line: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`addItem does have a correct value if I print it to the logs. Any ideas?

Comment: `CustomCell()` actually creates a new instance of the cell.

Comment: understood. but with the function not beeing in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` i cannot use `cell.button` to refer to the outlet. What can I do?

Comment: why can't you set it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`? Can you post a new question detailing your requirements?